# How to set up correct loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I have a excel file, and have many sheets which name by unit1, unit2, unit3...etc
and in each sheet, I have format like below

```
 KPI        | Actual     | Fc         |
 Revenue    | 30000      | 30000      | 
 Cost       | 20000      | 15000      | 
 Expense    | 10000      | 5000       |
```

i write the code as below

```
wb = load_workbook(filename = r'D:\filename.xlsx')
for name in wb.sheetnames:
    df = pd.read_excel(r'D:\filename.xlsx', sheet_name=name)
    Kpi=df['KPI'].values.tolist()
    Actual=df['Actual'].values.tolist()
    Fc=['Fc'].values.tolist()
    lenth=len(Actual)
    unit=[name]*lenth
    typeFC=['Fc']*lenth
    typeAct=['Actual']*lenth
    for w, x, y1,z1 in zip(unit,Kpi,typeAct, Actual):
        a=[w,x,y1,z1]
        print(a)
    for w,x,y2, z in zip(unit,Kpi, typeFc,Fc):
        b=[w,x,y2,z2]
        print(b)
```

I got tons of lists that contain 4 items like below

```
[unit1,revenue,Actual,30000]
[unit1,revenue,Fc,30000]
[unit1,Cost,Actual,20000]
[unit1,Cost,Fc,15000]
[unit2,revenue,Actual,value]
[unit2,revenue,Fc,value]
[unit2,Cost,Actual,value]
[unit2,Cost,Fc,value]
```

...etc

However, what i want to have is ONE list of lists that shows

```
[[unit1,revenue,Actual,30000],[unit1,revenue,Fc,30000]
 [unit1,Cost,Actual,20000],[unit1,Cost,Fc,15000]
 [unit2,revenue,Actual,value],[unit2,revenue,Fc,value]
 [unit2,Cost,Actual,value],[unit2,Cost,Fc,value]..etc]
```

Can someone hint that how can I improve my loop structure to achieve that?
Thanks

Comment: Use some data instead of `value` so we'll understand better what you exactly want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already have all of the values for your list, the only thing left to do is join them together. You can create a list at the beginning and append each element to it as your program runs:

```cs
wb = load_workbook(filename = r'D:\filename.xlsx')
result = [] # <-
for name in wb.sheetnames:
    df = pd.read_excel(r'D:\filename.xlsx', sheet_name=name)
    Kpi=df['KPI'].values.tolist()
    Actual=df['Actual'].values.tolist()
    Fc=['Fc'].values.tolist()
    lenth=len(Actual)
    unit=[name]*lenth
    typeFC=['Fc']*lenth
    typeAct=['Actual']*lenth
    for w, x, y1,z1 in zip(unit,Kpi,typeAct, Actual):
        a=[w,x,y1,z1]
        result.append(a) # <-
    for w,x,y2, z in zip(unit,Kpi, typeFc,Fc):
        b=[w,x,y2,z2]
        result.append(b) # <-
```